# Use jQuery to find element in DOM

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using jQuery to check if an element exists but my code doesn't work...can someone please explain me what I'm doing wrong?

If `variable-list-wrapper` has an element with class `empty-list-caption` then add `color blue` to the table.

HTML:

```
   <div class="variable-list-wrapper">
        <table tabindex="0" class="variable-list table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Value</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr class="not-sortable">
                <td colspan="1000">
                  <var class="empty-list-caption">No variables</var>
                </td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($(".variable-list-wrapper").hasClass("empty-list-caption")) {
    $("table.variable-list").css("color","blue");
  }
});
```

Comment: what type of element you actually want to get using jquery ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hasClass` is used to determine if the selected element has a class applied to it, not find a child element.

To do what you require, you could use `find()` and check the `length` property to determine if anything was found, like this:

```
if ($(".variable-list-wrapper").find(".empty-list-caption").length) {
    $("table.variable-list").css("color", "blue");
}
```

Alternatively you could use the `:has` selector which would negate the need for the `if` statement:

```
$(".variable-list-wrapper:has(.empty-list-caption) table.variable-list").css("color", "blue");
```

Note that it would also be better practice to set the styles in your CSS file and then add or remove a class to the element with jQuery.

Comment: One more `$("table.variable-list").toggleClass('blue', $(".variable-list-wrapper .empty-list-caption").length);`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `find()`, like below :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($(".variable-list-wrapper").find(".empty-list-caption").length == 1) {
    $("table.variable-list").css("color","blue");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should better use ".length" to your parent or child element:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($(".variable-list-wrapper").length){
      $("table.variable-list").css("color","blue");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($(".variable-list-wrapper").length){
      $("table.variable-list").css("color","blue");
    }
});
```